# C# Creating ZIP file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using IonicZip for creating Zip files of uploaded files in C#, I have followed [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5089e0/how-to-create-zip-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp/)

Every thing is working fine but when I open the created Zip, it has folder Struture like the whole path of my C# project

eg if my project is in  `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ZipUploadTest\ZipUploadTest`

It makes Zip like

```
User > Admin> Documents> visual studio 2010>Projects > ZipuploadTest > MyFolderwhere I am saving Zip file
```

I want to make Zip with just my File name, ie when I open the Zip file, it directly show my file
this is how I am creating Zip files

```
 private void MakeZip(string fname)
        {
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                string pathname = Server.MapPath("~/FileUpload/ZipFile/");
                string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(pathname);

                 foreach (string filename in filenames)
                 {             

                ZipEntry e = zip.AddFile(filename);                
                  }                
                zip.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Zips/abc.zip"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Care to share what code you are using at the moment or do we need to guess?

Comment: You have posted a very similar question a few hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444384/how-to-create-and-upload-zip-files. Why don't you improve the original question?

Comment: @SteveB that question was another issue, I was asking about how to implement this functionality, I got answer their but it got deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the file to the ZIP archive, provide the second parameter that identifies the directory to put the file in:

```
zip.AddFile(filename, "");
```

See [the documentation](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/202e1fb5-8891-888f-8e91-1340f7cd80c9.htm) for more info.